# Concept problem for tangent vector

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let M be a smooth manifold,the set of all linear maps $v:C^\infty(M)\to \mathbb{R}$ with product rule forms the tangent space $T_pM$.

My question is why element $v\in T_pM$ acts on a function $f\in C^\infty(U)$ such that $U$ is a neighborhood around $p$ is valid?I know $v$ acts on $f$ only locally,but the definition $f$ must be the one that defined on the whole manifold that is $f$ must in $C^\infty(M)$ instead of $C^\infty(U)$?

given a smooth chart $(U,(x^i))$ for smooth manifold M,the coordinate function $x^i$ also is defined only on $U$ not the whole manifold M correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the coordinate is only defined on the open set of your chart.

To see why the alternative definition holds: suppose that you have two functions $f,g:M\to\mathbb{R}$ such that there is an open neighborhood $U$ of a point $p\in M$ such that $f|_U=g|_U$. Then we will show that for all tangent vectors $v\in T_pM$, we have $vf=gf$.

First note that, by linearity, this is equivalent to show that $vh=0$ for all $h:M\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $h|_U=0$. Then, choose a bump function $\varphi:M\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi$ equals $1$ on a neighborhood of $p$ and $\mathrm{supp}\,\varphi\subset U$. Set $\psi=1-\varphi$. Since the functions $h$ and $\psi\times h$ are equal, using the product rule we get

$$vh=v(\psi\times h)=v\psi\times \underbrace{h(p)}_{=0}+\underbrace{\psi(p)}_{=0}\times vh,$$

and thus to $vh=0$.

Comment: Thanks,Do you mean $v\in T_p M$  acts on $f\in C^\infty(U)$ is valid,since we actually acts on the smooth extension of this $f$ which in $C^\infty (M)$ correct?

Comment: Yes, the above shows (there is a little mistake I'll correct soon!) that the map $T_pU\to T_pM$ given by $v\mapsto (\tilde{v}:f\mapsto v(f|_U))$ is $1-1$, and actually it is an isomorphism (here $U$ is a manifold with the structure induced by being an open set of the manifold $M$).